# Injecting 'this' with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I just started using Ninject and I have a question. Lets say I have a TaxCalculator class that has constructor with Sale paramter. Then I have Sale class with ITaxCalculator member. Normaly i would create TaxCalculator instance in Sale construcor giving 'this' as a parameter.

```
public class Sale
{
    private ITaxCalculator taxCalculator;

    public Sale()
    {
        this.taxCalculator = new TaxCalculator(this);
    }
}

public class TaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator
{
    private Sale sale;
    public TaxCalculator(Sale sale)
    {
        this.sale = sale;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using Ninject? Code below obviously doesn't work.

```
public class Sale
{
    private ITaxCalculator taxCalculator;

    [Inject]
    public void SetTaxCalculator(ITaxCalculator taxCalculator)
    {
        this.taxCalculator = taxCalculator;
    }
}

....
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
        {
            Sale sale = null;

            kernel.Bind<ITaxCalculator>()
                  .To<TaxCalculator>()
                  .WithConstructorArgument("sale", sale);

            sale = kernel.Get<Sale>();
        }
```

What I would like Ninject to do is to call SetTaxCalculator method after calling Sale constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so using property injection.

But having such circular dependencies means you have some flaw in your design. I strongly recommend to fix that structural problem so that just one of the classes needs a reference to the other.

e.g. why needs the tax calculator a reference to sale? let sale call the calculator and pass all the required information. E.g. `CalculateTax(products)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, in my application I have more complex problem than I had written here as an example. Nevertheless I'll consider what you suggested.
And property injection is probably what I was looking for, thanks.